# Meaning of "originating" in the context

Tags: meaning, adjectives, present-participles

In the computer science, the program is processed as a sequence of commands which is called "control flow". At some point, it branches and a different branch of code is processed.
In an article I read, they refer they use the term "originating flow" as a name for a flow which can branch into other ones.

As a non-native speaker, I have a problem with understanding. Why it is not just *original flow*? I do understand that they might mean it as a flow from which the other flows originate, but isn't there a synonym?

To make it clear: I would need to understand the exact meaning of "originating" in this context. I sense the difference but cannot say if it is right — original I would perceive as a former, earlier one. *Originating* seems to be "the one from which the other ones originate". The dictionary cannot help me here as it is in context and English is not my native language.

Comment: Welcome to [english.se]. Your question seems to be the difference between "original" and "originating". As it stands this question is incomplete. Please edit to show research you did before asking an expert. For example, dictionary definitions you compared, and what you found confusing about them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because it does not appear in several control-flow resources ([1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_flow),[2](http://cs.au.dk/~jmi/Midtgaard-CSur-final.pdf),[3](http://plg.uwaterloo.ca/usystem/pub/uSystem/uC++book.pdf)) where it might reasonably do so if it were standard control-flow terminology, the phrase *originating flow* appears to be either non-standard or perhaps a nonce usage.  That said, *originating* emphasizes, more than *original* does, where something starts from or is created.  Data origins are of concern in flow analysis:

> Control-flow analysis is concerned with flows-from information, i.e., inferring the origin of function values that may occur at a given expression. Escape analysis on the other hand is concerned with flows-to information, i.e., inferring where function values originating at a given lambda expression may occur. –  ([2](http://cs.au.dk/~jmi/Midtgaard-CSur-final.pdf), §8.4)

It is possible the authors were influenced by a communications background.  In a [google](http://www.google.com/#hl=en&output=search&sclient=psy-ab&q=originating+flow&oq=originating+flow&gs_l=hp.12..0i22i30l4.1007.1007.0.2930.1.1.0.0.0.0.114.114.0j1.1.0...0.0...1c..8.psy-ab.rUXIyG5suws&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_qf.&bvm=bv.44770516,d.cGE&fp=a3d5b513f8c4066a&biw=1052&bih=578) search for  *originating flow* many of the references include phrases like *GSM Mobile Originating Call Flow*.